# How can I add a curve to a pre-existing mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves

I apologize if this is easily answered, or found in the forums.  If so, I have spent the last 2 days using incorrect search terms to find the answer, and I will gladly use existing resources.

I have a model of a grip for a handgun that needs to include a compound curve.  The actual grip has a convex curve on the Y-axis,[image] and localized concave curves, or at least less pronounced convex curves, in a couple of spots on the X-axis.[image]  However, the Blender model has a flat top that I need to find a way to modify to approximate the real thing.[image]

I can subdivide the plane using Knife Project, so I have tried sculpting, and while that sort of works, I am TERRIBLE at it, and cannot build anything useful.  I've also tried deforming using proportional editing, but that has its own limitations, such as modifying the entire mesh.  I THINK, and I may be completely incorrect, that using a path curve may do what I need, but I cannot find anything that will tell me how to build the curve, then attach it to the plane so that the plane will match my curves.  Please help point me in the correct direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have different curves, you can join them all together with CTRL-J, then "convert to mesh", then TAB -> edit mode, A -> select all, and then Edge->Bridge edge loops is one way to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: I will take a crack at this.  Thank you!

Comment: This more or less worked.  It was a bit fiddly since the curved mesh needed to go with the base in the picture up top, but it got me 90% of the way there, and then it didn;t take much to fit the pieces together.  Since I am going to be modifying the piece further, this worked perfectly fine.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped you